# Node HTTP server on Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku

I am using Node's basic `http` module. I have it serving static files on my localhost test setup. Using `mime-types` and `find-my-way` it successfully retrieves static files and serves them with the correct headers. Wireshark also confirms this (ie it's not the browser doing some guesswork).

When I deploy my app to Heroku, everything starts up the same, but going to `/` does not return `index.html` but instead it downloads as a file called `download`. Wireshark shows no HTTP traffic.

My `Procfile` is

```
web: node index.js
```

And I am using `process.env.PORT || 80` for the port.

What else could be wrong? I followed the Heroku/express basic tutorial and it worked fine.

---

Here's how I generate a response in Node. All headers are preserved EXCEPT for `Content-type`.

```
let stats = await this.getFileStats(filepath);
let readable = Fs.createReadStream(filepath);
let contentType = Mime.contentType(filepath);
response.on('error', (err) => {
    readable.end();
});
readable.pipe(response);
response.setHeader('Content-Type', contentType);
response.setHeader('Content-Length', stats.size);
response.setHeader('X-Content-Type-Options', 'nosniff')
response.statusCode = 200;
```

**This is a localhost result**

[image]

**This is hosted on Heroku**

[image]

Comment: Hard to say. Can you post relevant code of your `index.js'. Also, are you sure that you have commited the html file into git??? (otherwise, it will not be uploaded to Heroku).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. We need more information.

Comment: @Sergio My index.js spawns a node HTTP server, listens on the provided port, and returns static files when requested. It works perfectly on m local machine. On Heroku, it instead downloads the index.html file as a file named "download". I know it is not a node problem but rather something I must be doing wrong with Heroku (first time using it).

Comment: "I know it is not a node problem but rather something I must be doing wrong with Heroku (first time using it)"—that's not for you to say. Please show us your `index.js` as Sergio requested, and read [ask] as I requested in my previous comment.

Comment: @Chris Sorry but it is 10000% Heroku deciding to change my `Content-type` header. I know this because every other header  I set, length, server, etc, is preserved. There must be some trick to tell Heroku not to do this.

Comment: @de-playable, for the _third_ time, please read [ask]. We can't help you if you refuse to share relevant information.

Comment: Okay I added some code and screenshots.

Comment: Are you confident that `Mime.contentType(filepath)` is returning what you expect it to on Heroku? Have you logged that value, or tried setting it manually to a hard-coded string? What is `Mime`? I guess you're using [this](https://github.com/jshttp/mime-types)?

Comment: Yes it logs out to the correct value. The first screenshot shows the headers I am setting. If I change `Content-Type` to something silly, it will reflect that. See example https://imgur.com/wjvYsPP. This results in the page loading as plain text on the browser.

Comment: The first screenshot is from your local machine. So is the one you just shared in a comment. Again, are you sure that that function returns the value you expect _on Heroku_? And you still haven't told us what `Mime` is. Is it the library I linked to? If that library is returning the wrong value, _that_ would be the source of your problem. I wouldn't be surprised if it falls back to the filename when it can't figure out a correct MIME type, which is what we see in your last screenshot.

Comment: In fact, assuming that's the library you're using, that's _exactly what is happening_. I'll add an answer.

Comment: Yeah.. you're right... I don't believe it. On my localhost the mime type is correct - how can it be wrong on Heroku? It should just infer from the file extension. Also it is quite specifically supposed to return false if it fails.

Comment: I guess it's a good idea to never be 10000% sure about something :-).

Comment: Yeah I guess I was only 9999% sure... Thanks for your patience, I was really about to try a different provider.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a complete solution. It looks like `contentType()` isn't supposed to take filenames at all. This was a long one, but I'm glad we got it figured out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `Mime` is an instance of [this library](https://github.com/jshttp/mime-types), your problem is not that Heroku is modifying any headers, but rather that

```js
Mime.contentType(filepath)
```

isn't returning the MIME type you expect.

If the string you pass into `contentType()` contains a slash, [the input string is returned as the MIME type](https://github.com/jshttp/mime-types/blob/47b62ac45e9b176a2af35532d0eea4968bb9eb6d/index.js#L83-L85), presumably because [MIME types contain slashes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_type#Naming) and you might have passed one in:

```
function contentType (str) {
  // ...
  var mime = str.indexOf('/') === -1
    ? exports.lookup(str)
    : str
  // ...
  return mime
}
```

(There's some extra logic that I left out here ensuring that the input is provided, that it is a string, and that `mime` returns a truthy value, and a bit more, but it's irrelevant here.)

**Edit:** Actually, the solution isn't to pass in just your filename without the path, but to use the correct *method*. `mime.contentType()` takes a file *extension* or a content type, not a filename:

> Create a full content-type header given a content-type or extension. When given an extension, `mime.lookup` is used to get the matching content-type, otherwise the given content-type is used.

You should be using `mime.lookup()` instead:

> Lookup the content-type associated with a file